# what's the meaning of “amt” in this roman numerals exercise?

Tags: ruby, roman-numerals

i just try to complete this quiz but i can't understand what is doing that "amt" in "romanize" method:

```
ROMAN_NUMS = {
  "M" => 1000,
  "CM" => 900, "D" => 500, "CD" => 400, "C" => 100,
  "XC" => 90,  "L" => 50,  "XL" => 40,  "X" => 10,
  "IX" => 9,   "V" => 5,   "IV" => 4,   "I" => 1
}

def romanize(num)
  ROMAN_NUMS.map do |ltr, val| 
    amt, num = num.divmod(val)
    ltr * amt
  end.join
end
```

Comment: [divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod)

Comment: When in doubt, search for method names like "Ruby divmod" and become enlightened.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i keep reading about "divmod" but i can't found some explain, i just notice it could be quotient derived from "divmod", but that becouse some good man tell me, however appreciate your recomendation. May i'll should ask "what try to describe 'amt' in method?"

Comment: If any method `m` (such as `divmod`), when executed on a receiver `r`, returns an array `a` of size two, you can write `x, y = r.m` and `x` will be set equal to the first element of `a` and `y` will be set equal to the second element of `a`. This can become more complex. For example suppose `r.m` returns `[[1,2],3,4]`. You can then set (try it!) `(a,b),c,d =  [[1,2],3,4]` and `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` will respectively equal `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. This combines "parallel assignment" with "disambiguation".

Comment: Excellent explaination!! Thanks f...ing a lot!!! Really :)

Answer (score 1):

`divmod` returns a 2-element array, made up of the quotient and the modulus.

So basically `x.divmod(y)` will return `[x / y, x % y]` (look at the docs for the more accurate description).

The line

```
amt, num = num.divmod(val)
```

takes that two element array and does a de-structuring assignment to two variables. Afterwards `amt` (which is just a badly named variable that should be called `amount`) will contain the first value of the returned array and `num` the second.

Comment: You could also write it in two lines: `amt = num / val` and `num = num % val`

Comment: Thats a more graphic and explicit way to see "divmod", thanks i really need it. You are kind!!